# Trying to setup server-side rendering (SSR) on Google Firebase hosting

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have an Angular 7 site, that works fine without server-side rendering (SSR).  I host it using Google's Firebase hosting. I now want to setup SSR.   I followed [this guide](https://hackernoon.com/deploying-angular-universal-v6-with-firebase-c86381ddd445) and got it to build and deploy to Firebase Hosting and Functions.

However, the site does not load and the Functions logs include this entry:

> ERROR ReferenceError: document is not defined
>       at new CssKeyframesDriver (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js:4246:26)
>       at instantiateSupportedAnimationDriver (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js:412:88)
>       at _callFactory (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:19867:24)
>       at _createProviderInstance (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:19825:30)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:19786:25)
>       at _createClass (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:19854:72)
>       at _createProviderInstance (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:19822:30)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:19786:25)
>       at _callFactory (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:19873:71)
>       at _createProviderInstance (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:19825:30)

Any ideas of what is wrong?  I can provide code snippets or individual read access to the repo if requested.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14784 ?

Comment: I will try this.  So I just add that module as an include at the top of my server module?

Comment: @yurzui I tried this, but to no avail.   PS: It also appears that wouldn't be an issue anymore since it was fixed in Angular 4.x and I am in Angular 7.

Answer (score 0):

Server side rendering probably means serving HTML from Node.js w Express.js.  In the Firebase suite of products, this is accomplished using Cloud Functions for Firebase's [HTTP triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).

You can have a look at [Firebase Samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples) on Github.  This is a relatively advanced implementation so proceed as long as you are strong in JavaScript, HTML, and CSS (not to mention Angular).

Answer (score 0):

Angular SSR is trying to run angular animations but it's not able to find any `document` variable(there is no `document` on server-side).
You can solve this by conditionally executing your code with the help of `isPlatformBrowser` and `isPlatformServer`.

example

Import this

```
import { Component, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';
```

User like this

```
constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: string){
    this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
    this.isServer = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
    if(this.isBrowser){
        //Do something on the browser
    }
    if(this.isServer){
        //Do something on the server
    }
}
```